Best practices for DNS suffixes on Windows DNS
I got a Windows Server 2016 ADDS that hosts corporate DNS server. To sum up, my_domain.net is the name of the domain and so, the name of root DNS.
There's no subdomain from an AD perspective, only one root domain is existing (domain.net).
For "management reasons" the DNS tree has been set up the following way :

domain.net

sub1

prod
test


sub2

prod
test
...
...





Once again and for example, prod.sub1.domain.net is only a DNS suffixes (there's no Active Directory sub-domain with that name).
At the moment, most servers records are registered through domain.net. From a client perspective (Windows AND Linux), DNS suffixes search list is only fill with domain.net
=> it means when you ping my_server, it resolves to my_server.domain.net.
Until here, everything is ok and understood.
Since few months, it has been decided to create DNS sub-domains i.e sub1, prod.
It means if i try to join/ping a server in a DNS subdomain without its FQDN it will always fail as it only search within domain.net.
From Windows client perspective, we thought that we can add all suffixes search list (~20) to fix this, and the same for Linux client, except Linux (Debian 11/12) resolv.conf only supports 6 search list.
Question :
Does this current DNS setup is fine ?
If yes, how can I manage the "recursive" search from clients ? like I want to ping my_server.test.sub2.domain.net and be sure search is recursive without specifying FQDN.

This isn't a "best practice" question. This is a "the two features to accomplish single label name resolution don't work for us, what other options are there"?

Linux got this right with the limit of 16 though, they probably saved you months of time.

Yes indeed, I'm aware it limits DNS requests to multiple domain (and so avoid long time resolution and requests) and that's a good design. However in my peculiar environment, currently don't know to handle this, if it may be handled.In an other hands, i have to test if AD sub-domain may workaround this.

that's why I'm asking for advices/best practices , maybe my current environment isn't properly setup and I could hear it. I don't want to find a workaround that makes me more problems than solution :)
